# Swift Center on Camera not working when ApplyingImpulse in another class

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm new to swift programming and have been stuck on this issue for the last week.  I am trying to centre on a hero while applying impulse to him.  My code works if I create a hero in the scene class and centre him but it doesn't work when I put a hero in another class and try to centre him from scene class.  Now centre on works if I just move him by changing his x or y position but not if I apply impulse.  It seems that when a hero is in a separate class, when impulse is applied x and y while he is in motion is showing up as a nil, however when he is in the same class than x and y while in the motion are showing up ok.  Any help is much appreciated.

Code where Center ON works with ApplyImpulse when everything is in the same class*****

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

  var hero:SKSpriteNode?
  var mazeWorld:SKNode?
  var player=Player()
  var heroLocation:CGPoint = CGPointZero

  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    mazeWorld = childNodeWithName("mazeWorld")
    heroLocation = mazeWorld!.childNodeWithName("sPoint")!.position

    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5,y: 0.3)

    hero?.position = heroLocation

    hero = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"hero_walk_down_0")
    hero!.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    hero!.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    hero!.physicsBody?.pinned = false
    hero!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: hero!.size)
    hero!.physicsBody?.mass = 1.0;
    hero!.setScale(0.8)

    mazeWorld!.addChild(hero!)
  }

  override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)  

  {
     /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
      hero!.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 240, dy: 550))
    }
  }

  override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
  }

  func centerOnNode(node:SKNode){

        let cameraPositionInScene:CGPoint = self.convertPoint(node.position, fromNode: mazeWorld!)

        mazeWorld!.position = CGPoint(x:mazeWorld!.position.x - cameraPositionInScene.x, y: mazeWorld!.position.y - cameraPositionInScene.y)
   }


   override func didSimulatePhysics() {
       self.centerOnNode(hero!)
   }



}
```

**** Here is the code with Center ON that doesn't work with apply impulse for some reason

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

  var hero:SKSpriteNode?
  var mazeWorld:SKNode?
  var player=Player()
  var heroLocation:CGPoint = CGPointZero

  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    mazeWorld = childNodeWithName("mazeWorld")
    heroLocation = mazeWorld!.childNodeWithName("sPoint")!.position

    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5,y: 0.3)

    player.position = heroLocation

    mazeWorld!.addChild(player)
  }

  override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) 

  {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        player.jumpRight()
    }
  }

  override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
  }


  func centerOnNode(node:SKNode){

        let cameraPositionInScene:CGPoint = self.convertPoint(node.position, fromNode: mazeWorld!)

        mazeWorld!.position = CGPoint(x:mazeWorld!.position.x - cameraPositionInScene.x, y: mazeWorld!.position.y - cameraPositionInScene.y)
    }


    override func didSimulatePhysics() {
       self.centerOnNode(player)
    }



}

import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Player: SKNode{

  var objectSprite:SKSpriteNode?

  override init()
  {
    super.init()

    objectSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"hero_walk_down_0")
    objectSprite!.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    objectSprite!.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    objectSprite!.physicsBody?.pinned = false
    objectSprite!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: objectSprite!.size)
    objectSprite!.physicsBody?.mass = 1.0
    objectSprite!.setScale(0.8)

    addChild(objectSprite!)

}

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  func jumpRight()
  {
       objectSprite!.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 240, dy: 550))
   }
}
```

Comment: This might help you out http://swiftalicio.us/2014/09/2d-camera-in-spritekit/